# Linq to get index

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

In my application I am using the below code to get the index (line number) of the desired content(I am using this in numerous times based on the skip/take index and search text). I am using Skip and Take depending on whether I have to search data after some or lines with in some lines. In both the case I am using First() instead of FirstOrDefault() as the text which I am searching will always exist.

```
Int myIndex = pSegments.Skip(nextIndex).Where(seg => (seg.Elements.ElementAt(0).Equals("MyTEXT")).Select(seg => seg.LineNumber).First();

Int myIndex = prodSegments.Take(testIndex).Where(seg => (seg.SegID.Equals("SOMETEXT") && seg.Elements.ElementAt(1).Equals(“SampleText”))).Select(seg => seg.LineNumber).First();
```

Where pSegments is -

```
IEnumerable<PSegment> pSegments;

   class PSegment
    {
        public string SegID { get; set; }
        public string[] Elements { get; set; }        
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }        
    }
```

It has not given me any problem till now. But is this the right approach to take for this kind of operation. Is there something which is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanup of your code:

```
int myIndex = pSegments.Skip(nextIndex)
    .First(seg => seg.Elements[0] == "MyTEXT")
    .LineNumber;

int myIndex = prodSegments.Take(testIndex)
    .First(seg => seg.SegID == "SOMETEXT" && seg.Elements[1] == "SampleText")
    .LineNumber;
```

It's hard to answer your main question because you didn't provide a lot of context, and I found your phrasing confusing.  But generally speaking, using `Skip` and `Take` like this would be pretty weird.  You should probably store the lines in some kind of data structure that supports fast random access if this is a common operation.

Comment: I have text file which I am loading into pSegments where each pSegemnt is a line from the text file. Another text file I will be loading into another set of segments .Now looping through one set of segments I search the data from another set of segments. While searching I make use of Skip/Take so that I don't search in all the segments